# Extended modelform not saving related table

Tags: django

I've extended a modelform but the related model isn't correctly saving to the database.
Below I'm only calling `SupplyAddress()` rather than creating and saving an instance of it via `SupplyAddress.objects.create()` However, if I try to do this then the related address (and user) hasn't been created yet to save against. What's the best way to save the user, `Address` and `SupplyAddress`?

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    house_name_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="house name or number")
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    time_stamp = models.DateField(auto_now=True)  

class SupplyAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, null=True)

    occupied = models.BooleanField()
```

forms.py

```
class SupplyAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    occupied = forms.BooleanField()    


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        data = self.cleaned_data
        supply_address = models.SupplyAddress(
            occupied=data['occupied'],
        )
        self.instance.supplyaddress = supply_address
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['house_name_number',
                  'street_name',
                  'town_city',
                  'county',
                  'same_address',
                  'move_in_date',
                  'postcode',
                  ]
```

views.py

```
.....
address = form.save(commit=False)
        address.user = user
        address.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your save method,

```
class SupplyAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    occupied = forms.BooleanField()    

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['house_name_number',
                  'street_name',
                  'town_city',
                  'county',
                  'same_address',
                  'move_in_date',
                  'postcode',
                  ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        supply_address = models.SupplyAddress.objects.create(occupied=data['occupied'])
        instance = super(SuppyAddressForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.supplyaddress = supply_address
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks but having `occupied` in the `Meta` `fields` list causes an error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (occupied) specified for Address` as occupied is on the related model SupplyAddress. Removing this and I get an error due to `SupplyAddress.objects.create()` having a null entry for the required field address (it needs an instance of the related model Address)

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Don't need to add in the fields. Try the save method.